# NLTK find german nouns

Tags: python, nltk

**I want to extract all german nouns from a german text in lemmatized form with NLTK.**

I also checked spacy but NLTK is much more preferred because in english it already works with the needed performance and requested data structure.

I have the following working code for english:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

#germanText='Jahrtausendelang ging man davon aus, dass auch der Sender einen geheimen Schlüssel, und zwar den gleichen wie der Empfänger, benötigt.'

text='For thousands of years it was assumed that the sender also needed a secret key, the same as the recipient.'

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tokens = [tok.lower() for tok in tokens]
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(tok) for tok in tokens]
tokens = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokens) if pos[0] == 'N']

print (tokens)
```

I get the print as expected:
`['year', 'sender', 'key', 'recipient']`

Now I tried to do this for German:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

germanText='Jahrtausendelang ging man davon aus, dass auch der Sender einen geheimen Schlüssel, und zwar den gleichen wie der Empfänger, benötigt.'
#text='For thousands of years it was assumed that the sender also needed a secret key, the same as the recipient.'

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(germanText, language='german')
tokens = [tok.lower() for tok in tokens]
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(tok) for tok in tokens]
tokens = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokens) if pos[0] == 'N']

print (tokens)
```

And I get a wrong result:
`['jahrtausendelang', 'man', 'davon', 'au', 'der', 'sender', 'einen', 'geheimen', 'zwar', 'den', 'gleichen', 'wie', 'der', 'empfänger', 'benötigt']`

The lemmatization did not work and the noun extraction did not work.

**How is the proper way to apply different languages to this code?**

I also checked other solutions like:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import GermanStemmer
stemmer = GermanStemmer("german") # Choose a language
tokenGer=stemmer.stem(tokens)
```

But this would make me start from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way with the HanoverTagger:

```
from HanTa import HanoverTagger as ht
tagger = ht.HanoverTagger('morphmodel_ger.pgz')
words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
print(tagger.tag_sent(words) )
tokens=[word for (word,x,pos) in tagger.tag_sent(words,taglevel= 1) if pos == 'NN']
```

I get the outcome as expected: `['Jahrtausendelang', 'Sender', 'Schlüssel', 'Empfänger']`